# WebGL doesn't work in Joomla web-site

Tags: javascript, html, joomla, webgl

My WebGL example doesn't work if I embed it into Joomla web site, example is pretty simple as there is only one spining cube in the scene as shown in that example [Code pen example-spiningcube](http://codepen.io/osgjs/pen/uxthp.)
    `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://osgjs.org/examples/vendors/Q.js"></script>`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://osgjs.org/examples/vendors/Hammer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://osgjs.org/examples/vendors/Leap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://osgjs.org/builds/active/OSG.js"></script>

<canvas id="3DView" width="100%" height="100%"></canvas>

<ul>Apply Rotation<ul>
    <li>Update time: <a id="update"></a></li>
    <li>Rotation angle: <a id="angle"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Normally this example has 2 files one for the HTML file and other for external reference to javascript files.

To make that work in Joomla 3.2.1, I created a Custom HTML module and embed it into one of the articles with `loadposition` command, but nothing is shown up in the page of web-site. I know that my browser supports WebGL, I noticed only one discrepancy if I open the related page of web site, where my embeded code starting with script `type="text/javascript"` is not in the head section of page, could that be a reason of why WebGL example is not working?